# Celery worker's log contains question marks (???) instead of correct unicode characters

Tags: python, logging, unicode, celery

I'm using Celery 3.1.18 with Python 2.7.8 on CentOS 6.5.

In a Celery task module, I have the following code:

```
# someapp/tasks.py
from celery import shared_task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)


@shared_task()
def foo():
    logger.info('Test output: %s', u"测试中")
```

I use [the initd script here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/daemonizing.html#generic-init-scripts) to run a Celery worker. Also I put the following settings in `/etc/default/celeryd`:

```
CELERYD_NODES="bar"

# %N will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%N.log"

# Workers should run as an unprivileged user.
#   You need to create this user manually (or you can choose
#   a user/group combination that already exists, e.g. nobody).
CELERYD_USER="nobody"
CELERYD_GROUP="nobody"
```

So my log file is located in `/var/log/celery/bar.log`.

However, once the task is executed by the worker, the above log file shows:

```
[2015-05-07 03:51:14,438: INFO/Worker-1/someapp.tasks.foo(...)] Test output: ???
```

The unicode characters are gone, replaced with a number of question marks.

How can I get back the unicode characters in the log file?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related with Celery? What happens if you do the same on a regular python script? Also what happens if you specify `u"测试中".encode('utf-8')` instead of just `u"测试中"`?

Comment: In a regular Python script, unicode logging is fine. Also, if I specify ```u"测试中".encode('utf-8')``` instead of ```u"测试中"``` in my example, the Celery log shows ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte...```.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8` in the environment in which you startup your celery application.

If you are using the `celeryd`, there is a simple way, set `CELERY_BIN="env LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 /path/to/celery/binary` in `/etc/default/celeryd`

**Explanation:**

1. Celery uses `ColorFormatter` for message formatting, which is
   defined in `celery.utils.log`.
2. `ColorFormatter` converts `unicode` to `str` with       `kombu.utils.encoding.safe_str`.
3. `kombu.utils.encoding.safe_str` encodes unicode to str with encoding
       returns by `default_encoding` defined in `kombu.utils.encoding`
4. `default_encoding` returns `getattr(get_default_encoding_file(), 'encoding', None) or sys.getfilesystemencoding()`
5. Besides, I did not find celery set encoding explicitly, so I thought celery is use `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` as encoding for convert unicode to str.
6. [sys.getfilesystemencoding's manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.getfilesystemencoding) says that:

> On Unix, the encoding is the user’s preference according to the result of nl_langinfo(CODESET), or None if the nl_langinfo(CODESET) failed
>
> So, setting `LANG=zh_CN.UTF8` in the celery process environment tells celery to convert unicode to str by UTF8.

Comment: Thanks. This really solves my problem. I still wonder how this works though.

Comment: @Rockallite Explanation added.

Comment: Very detailed answer! I try to run ```LANG= python -c 'import sys; print sys.getfilesystemencoding()'``` on CentOS, and it says ```ANSI_X3.4-1968```. Without the ```LANG=``` part, it says ```UTF-8``` (by default it's ```LANG=en_US.UTF-8``` in the bash shell). ```kombu``` encodes unicode to str with ```error='replace'``` argument, so anything beyond ANSI becomes question marks.